# How to formulate JPQL query with or without parameter?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

For example take this jpql query -

```
@Query("SELECT account.name, account.type From AccountEntity account WHERE account.id=:accountId")
getAccountNameById(@Param(accountId) int accountId); //i know Spring Data Derived Query can handles this automatically - but lets not use this for this discussion.
```

in the above jpql query, if no accountId is passed, i want to select records for all accountId's. Is it possible. I know i can use another query - getAllAccounts() and call it from service layer based on accountId is present or not. But I have to handle it from repo in this case.

So is it possibel that JPQL returns all records when parm value is missing or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit late but...

In this example the 1st WHEN is going to evaluate :accountId
if it's null then the query is going to return all elements,
in the 2nd WHEN if :accountId is not null then is going to return all elements
where account.id = :accountId

```
SELECT account.name, account.type FROM AccountEntity account 
WHERE CASE WHEN :accountId IS NULL THEN TRUE
WHEN :accountId IS NOT NULL AND account.id = :accountId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

Comment: flanker - can you look at this [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854697/hibernate-ast-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-ast-node-error). The comment from jens says that `CASE` is not supported in `WHERE` in JPQL. Could you confirm.

Answer (score 0):

test if parameter is null

```
SELECT account.name, account.type From AccountEntity account WHERE (:accountId is null or account.id=:accountId)
```

Comment: no grigouile, i doubt your query will work. (1) If I pass `accountId` as 4, then it will select records with accountId 4 or null.   (2) And if `accountId` passed is `null` or empty. Then the query will select only those where `accountId` is null.  In this case I want select all accounts including accountId 4.

Comment: If you pass 4 the you get : "4 is null or account.id=4". Because "4 is null" is false, you get "account.id=4". If you pass null you get: ""null is null" which is true and you select all accounts. Just try it.