# Hibernate - .ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node error?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, case, jpql

My JPQL Query is as below -

```
@Query("SELECT p.packageName FROM Packages p WHERE CASE WHEN :packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN p.packageId.packageId=:packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END")
List<String> getPackageByAccountIdAndPackageId(Long packageId);
```

I am facing below error on compiling the above code -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: CASE near line 1, column 80 [SELECT p.packageName FROM com.entities.Packages p WHERE CASE WHEN p.packageId.packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN p.packageId.packageId=:packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: CASE near line 1, column 80 [SELECT p.packageName FROM com.entities.Packages p WHERE CASE WHEN p.packageId.packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN p.packageId.packageId=:packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Any guidance/help on how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated.

I am using spring-data-jpa - 2.1.7.RELEASE and hibernate core - 5.3.10.FINAL

Comment: BTW Your where clause does not make any sence. What you are tying todo?

Comment: @Jens - i can improve the query but if `CASE` is not supported for sure in JPQL then i have to see other alternatives like native query.  But I see [this](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-case-expressions.html) example - `CASE` is supported in JPQL Select.

Comment: But not in a where clause

Comment: @Jens - i corrected the Query `@Query("SELECT p.packageName FROM Packages p WHERE CASE WHEN :packageId IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN p.packageId.packageId=:packageId THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END")`  . Now I think it makes sense.  But the error is same..  as CASE is not supported as per you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I answered on [Discourse](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-ast-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-ast-node-error/6689/2) already, you have to use a query like this instead:

```sql
SELECT p.packageName 
FROM Packages p 
WHERE p.packageId.packageId IS NULL 
OR p.packageId.packageId=:packageId
```

Comment: That works +1 .. but in general - HQL seems to support `CASE` in where clause. could you confirm if `JPQL` supports the same or not.

Comment: JPQL and HQL both support the case expression, but an expression is not a predicate and the where clause requires predicates. In Hibernate 6 we added support for boolean expressions as predicates, but you'll have to wait until Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3 for Hibernate 6 to become available.